# Error using geopandas to_crs epsg "no columns showing"

Tags: python, arcpy, geopandas, epsg

I have this code and I run it and it's all good but when I use.head() no raw in columns showing and the rest of the codes didn't run because the raws are emputy..

this is the code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point, box
import ast
from pyproj import Proj
```

```
paths = road_features.SHAPE.map(lambda x: np.array(ast.literal_eval(x)["paths"][0]))
pathLineStrings = paths.map(LineString)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(road_features,geometry=pathLineStrings)
#gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:3857'}
gdf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

```
gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
x0 = -112.8
x1 = -111.0
y0 = 39.6
y1 = 41.6
SLC = box(x0,y0,x1,y1)

slc_df = gdf[gdf.intersects(SLC)]
```

i run

```
slc_df.head()
```

shows this

```
segment_id
OBJECTID_1
Join_Count
TARGET_FID
Join_Count_1
TARGET_FID_1
Join_Count_12
TARGET_FID_12
OBJECTID
pre_dir
...
road_orient_approx
proximity_to_signal
proximity_to_billboard
proximity_to_nearest_intersection
proximity_to_major_road
population_density
station_id
SHAPE
accident_counts
geometry

0 rows × 32 columns
```

Did I miss something?
thank you for year time

Comment: this important part of my machine learning part if you don't know its GEAI...

Comment: Tags have to do with the *content* of the question, not the context; you may have very well been developing this for a space application, but this would not make it appropriate for `space-engineering` tag...

Comment: If the result is empty (no rows), that means that none of the rows intersected with the `SLC` box. Are you sure they intersect? Eg you can plot them first to check this.